# PHP, JavaScript - Is it right to detect screen-width by redirecting header

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following JavaScript to detect the screen-width and use it as a constant across my template files through conditional statements to display / not-display portions of my site. While it has nothing much to do with my questions, but just in case... Yes I am using WordPress. Also I am already using mobiledetect PHP Library.

```
function getLayoutWidth() {

        if (isset($_GET['width'])) {
          define( "SCREEN_WIDTH", $_GET['width']);
        } else {
          echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
          echo "  location.href=\"${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?${_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}"
                        . "&width=\" + screen.width;\n";
          echo "</script>\n";
          exit();
        }
    }
```

**Important :**

1. Other techniques are like...... Let's assume if my site is 2MB in size, it will still load 2MB of content and then hide 1.5MB of it on mobile devices by using CSS properties like `display:none;` Whereas I don't want that template part to load itself, thus not needing to hide anything.
2. I am not looking to load an entire JavaScript library like jQuery or so to do this because `location.href=\"${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?${_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}". "&width=\" + screen.width;` is the only JavaScript in my entire site. Rest everything is pure PHP, HTML and CSS based. I even disabled jQuery of WordPress in the front-end template.

**UPDATE :**
Since some friends did not get my point although I mentioned clearly that I don't want to load the content into DOM at all, I am giving a bit more clarity here.....

For Example --- @1200px I want only 1 Sidebar to be displayed. @1600px I want 2 Sidebars to be displayed and over 1600px I want 3 Sidebars to be displayed. Please don't suggest Media Queries solutions as I already know it and that is exactly what I don't want to do. I want to avoid loading the content into DOM. Kindly let focus be only and only on questions asked. Also please don't post suggestions as answers. Let others with proper answers do it. Kindly post suggestions in Comment section.

**My questions :**

1. Is this a good / correct way to do from SEO stand point? If not why?
2. My URL is displayed as `example.com/my-product-category/my-product-name/?width=1440` How to remove `/?width=1343` and display just `example.com/my-product-category/my-product-name` part?

Comment: Personally if I wanted to get the screen dimensions I would set a cookie. If the cookie doesn't exist, set it - otherwise read it ( should be able to read in both js and php )

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks for the suggestion. Well I am really bad at that part of programming. I am primarily a HTML / CSS guy. Would you be kind enough to answer this question with some PHP code to set and read cookie

Comment: You need to be doing this with CSS and not php/jscript

Comment: You are aware that JS has "document.body.clientWidth", right?

I mean, I love PHP, but why does it care much about the client width?

Comment: Are you doing it this way just because you are uncomfortable with javascript? You certainly don't need to load jquery, and setting the screen width in a GET where javascript is disabled or it's a robot means you still have to deal with requests where width is not set. Plus your url looks crazy, and will continue to look that way unless you implement another redirect and tell your javascript hey - I saw the first redirect, so don't do it again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer, no, it is not good from a SEO standpoint. Or any other standpoint. Crawlers such as Googles are designed to completely ignore all `hidden` elements and thus you will lose big time SEO ranking if your content isnt getting fully crawled, and crawlers crawl each site multiple times masquerading as mobile devices to check if the site is mobile friendly as well.
http://www.seonick.net/responsive-design-seo/

Not to mention the trouble of calculating your arbitrary cutoff point of .5mb serves no purpose if the content is merely hidden (since its all getting sent anyway thus saving no bandwidth).

You need to do this in pure CSS using media queries, it is the most compatible way and allows for a fluid design (changes on the go as the window resizes.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 700px)" href="mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 700px)" href="full.css">
```

That will use one css file if the window is smaller than 700px and the other if it is over.

Another of my more favorite methods is to use the http://mobiledetect.net/ class. Its small and fast, more accurate and better flexibility. Load that class then just add classes to your body element depending on the visitors browser

```
<body class="<?PHP if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()) echo " .phone";?>">
```

Then style by targeting classes inside `body.phone`. This method also ensures you know if the browser is mobile BEFORE the DOM starts to process, meaning you can serve compressed versions of images through some simple logic rather than having CSS swap them out or just resize them or omit entire parts of the markup from being sent to the user at all ensure bandwidth is only used for parts of the DOM relevant to the users device.

```
<body>
This is normal content and will be visible to all devices
<?PHP if (!$detect->isMobile()) { ?>
This content will only be visible to desktop users, in fact it wont even be transmitted to mobile users thus making it NOT in the DOM
<?PHP } ?>
</body>
```

Comment: You are trying to stop data flow after a certain amount of transfer, thats a bad way to do things for mobile users and just in general, and a css hidden attribute does not keep the data from loading into the DOM, it just makes it hidden visible thus not accomplishing anything. Im trying to show you the way you SHOULD do it thus eliminating your issues altogether.

Comment: @Vikram Rao, the second part of my answer covers that, you need to read the answer.

Comment: @Vikram Rao `<?PHP if ($isMobile) { \\Mobile markup } else { \\Normal markup};?> its not that hard to filter out elements for targeted devices.

Comment: Stop with the arbitrary screen resolutions, and if its not mobile, then it IS desktop, its just a simple logic if then else statement at that point. `if (!$detect->isMobile()){\\if im not mobile than I am a DESKTOP }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92584/discussion-between-vikram-rao-and-wobbles).

Comment: HOW? Give me an example for.... At 1200px I want only 1 Sidebar to be displayed. At1600px I want 2 Sidebars to be displayed and over 1600px I want 3 Sidebars to be displayed. Now show me how to write a conditional statement for At 1200px, At 1600px and Greater Than1600px? (all on Desktop itself, forget my customization for Mobile and Tablets). Only possible with Media Queries but again I'll have to load the content in DOM and then hide. My layout is way more complicated.. Which is exactly what I don't want. Just arguing without getting the question does not make it right. Sorry to say that.

Comment: Your question says absolutely nothing about hiding sidebars at certain resolutions, that's on you for not posting a clear and concise question.

Comment: And eliminating a sidebar completely from the DOM while the browser is still a desktop browser but just a different res is bad practice. It forces the user to refresh each time they change windows size to show hide elements that should just be handled by CSS in a fluid design.

Comment: Still none of your suggestions answer any of my questions.

Comment: You asked if what you are doing is a good / correct way to do it, we say no and several of us have tried to suggest proper ways to design a fluid responsive site and you say you would rather do it your way... Not sure what more help we can be.

Comment: Because, if its not in the DOM during certain crawls you could lose the SEO impact the content could have. There is a reason for using a multistep process at the server level to first determine mobile or desktop user then at the client side if it is a desktop user display a fluid design dependent on resolution. If it is a desktop browser stop worrying about bandwidth and the DOM and at that point just try to make it as fluid as possible a design, and you cannot do that if all your DOM handling for different resolutions is being done server side.

Answer (score 3):

To set a cookie in javascript

```
function Cookies(){};
Cookies.prototype.save=function(name,value,days){
    if( days ) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime( date.getTime()+( days*24*60*60*1000 ) );
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        var dom = "; domain="+document.domain;
    } else { expires = ""; }
    var path = "; path=/";
    var tmp=[];
    if( typeof( value )=='object' ) {
        for( p in value ) tmp.push( p+'='+value[ p ] );
        value=tmp.join(';');    
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+path;
};
Cookies.prototype.read=function(name){
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for( var i=0; i < ca.length;i++ ) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while( c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if( c.indexOf( nameEQ ) == 0 ) return c.substring( nameEQ.length, c.length );
        }
        return null;
};
Cookies.prototype.erase=function(name){
    this.save( name, "", -1 );
};



var cn='jsdim';
var ckie=new Cookies;
ckie.save( cn, JSON.stringify({ width:screen.availWidth, height:screen.availHeight, colour:screen.colorDepth, depth:screen.pixelDepth }), 1 );
```

In PHP

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_COOKIE['jsdim'] ) ){
        $json=json_decode( $_COOKIE['jsdim'] );
        if( !defined('SCREEN_WIDTH') ) define( 'SCREEN_WIDTH', $json->width );
        if( !defined('SCREEN_HEIGHT') ) define( 'SCREEN_HEIGHT', $json->height );
        if( !defined('SCREEN_COLOUR_DEPTH') ) define( 'SCREEN_COLOUR_DEPTH', $json->colour );
        if( !defined('SCREEN_PIXEL_DEPTH') ) define( 'SCREEN_PIXEL_DEPTH', $json->depth );
    }
?>
```

Comment: ok, but what if cookies are disabled in the browser? And for the first request the cookie is not set, so this is useless...

Comment: it's a good point about being disabled in the browser but if you examine the original code the php constant would not be declared until after javascript had been invoked and reloaded the page anyway. I agree with the use of CSS to achieve a fluid layout rather than lots of chicanery like above, but the OP wanted to set the width as a constant so it was merely a suggestion:)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think, that screen size/resolution is really what you want to adjust your view templates for mobile devices. Actually you want to know what plattform/device someone is using, think about Nexus 7, which has 1920 × 1200 or Sony Xperia Z5 with 2160 x 3840px.

I would look at user-agent and HTTP headers for the server side code, there are already good libraries for that: e.g. [mobiledetect](http://mobiledetect.net/). For the client side the best practice is to use CSS3 Media Queries: [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: @VikramRao why do you think, that 1024px, 1600px or larger than 1600px are Desktop Screens?? You should read some literature/blog posts about Front End Development before posting such questions..

Comment: I really don't care if they are desktop screens or not. Please focus on my questions. I've mentioned my requirement very clearly. Kindly read them again.

Answer (score 0):

You can retire the $_GET of the URL by the htaccess, I'm using **RewriteRule**.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^folder/file.php$ folder/file.php?g=2
#if you want to remove php file extension, don't keep the .php before the $
```

To remove all php files extension: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php).

Edit: this is for who doesn't use Wordpress

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I just performed a test this still loads the content, it just doesn't show it. The Asker pointed this out in the opening post already.

Comment: @Xesau You must remember that changing its URL by htaccess will modify file location, then it's recommended to load scripts and styles with the website url (`$wurl="http://website.com"; - <script src='<? echo $wurl; ?>/js/some.js'></script>`). And I removed the CSS media queries part of the answer, ;|

Comment: Also the question was not how to hide the .php-extension.

Comment: @Xesau Yeah, but this will remove the $_GET, and it's good to remove .php extension.

Comment: Which is what Wordpress does for you

Comment: I never used Wordpress, but I know a bit it by the look. Then my example mayn't be usable on it, I think. It depends, and sorry if Wordpress already has this option.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/mobble/
It adds an `is_mobile()`-feature.

In your theme you can now use `is_mobile()` instead of `$_GET['width'] > ...`
This way you don't need a `?width=` in your `$_GET`

Comment: Funnily my answer gets downvoted, while 'Wobbles' says exactly the same and gets upvoted. ...

Comment: I actually upvoted you because the OP downvoting all of the devs on here trying to teach proper responsive design development is funny. Infact all the answers while valid were downvoted by him. And your post is 2 sentences, hardly an answer, whereas I have a couple paragraphs with links, examples, and an explination as to why no responsive design is bad for SEO, so no, not "exactly the same"

Comment: @Wobbles I had another answer, which I deleted because of the downvote the OP gave, and those which followed (people tend to downvote answers which have a negative reputation already), but offered a solution either. I flagged the question nonetheless